# Agregar un salto de línea en un Tooltip

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap

Estoy intentando que en un *Tooltip* pueda haber un salto de línea.

```
<i class="fa fa-group" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" 
    data-original-title="--- Aquí hago un for pero los valores que me devuelve me los pone seguidos.">
</i>
```

He intentado con `/n` y `<br>`, y muchas más cosas, pero no hace el salto de línea en el *Tooltip*.

Dentro del `title` como puse en el código, hice un `for` para que me recorriera una lista y me mostrara unos resultados, pero cuando me los muestra tengo que separarlos con `---`, porque de lo contrario me los pone seguidos, por lo que quiero que me salgan uno debajo del otro.

Comment: Livian por favor desarrolla tu pregunta a manera de expliques que sucede cuando haces qué y qué esperas que suceda. ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: he intentado con /n <br> y muchas mas pero no hace el salto de linea en el tooltip, dentro del tiitle como puse en el codigo hice un for para que me recorriera una lista y me mostrara unos resultados, pero cuando me los muestra tengo que separarlos con --- porque sino me los pone seguidos, por lo que quiero que me salgan uno debajo del otro, saludos

Comment: Te damos la Bienvenida a StackOverflow en Español. Te invito a que pases por el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leas el artículo [Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida.

Comment: @LivanRamirezBrito van a eliminar tu pregunta si no la formulas correctamente, así que tomate tu tiempo. saludos.

Answer (score 3):

## `\n`

Insertando un salto de línea directamente en el texto del tooltip. El caracter no debe estar escapado, sino que debería ser efectivamente el literal `"\n"`.

En la documentación de [*Atributos Globales > title*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Atributos_Globales/title), se menciona:

> El atributo title puede contener varias líneas . Cada  U+000A LINE FEED (LF) insertada representa una línea nueva .

Ejemplo:

```html
<i title="Valor 1
Valor 2
Valor 3
Valor 4">
         Texto
 </i>
```

---

## `&#10;`

Es la entidad HTML para el caracter `\n` (ASCII 10). Es una forma de insertar un salto de línea en un tooltip.

Ejemplo

```html
<i title="Valor 1&#10;Valor 2&#10;Valor 3&#10;Valor 4">
         Texto
 </i>
```

---

## En Bootstrap, con `white-space: pre-wrap`

Usando Bootstrap, es necesario asignar cómo tratar los espacios en blanco mediante CSS.

```css
.tooltip-inner {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Ejemplo:

```js
//Inicializamos el tooltip
$("#ejemplo").tooltip();
```

```css
.tooltip-inner {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- HTML -->
<i id="ejemplo"
    class="fa fa-group" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" 
    data-original-title="aqui hago un for
pero los valores que me devuelve
me los pone en diferentes líneas">
  Texto
</i>
```

Answer (score 2):

La forma mas simple y efectiva de poner saltos de linea es agregar el comando  `data-html="true"` y con eso el `tootip` ya soporta comandos `html` como `<br>`

Comment: Por favor lee [answer]

Comment: Es de resaltar que esta es la forma más simple de hacerlo pero sólo si usas Bootstrap, en versiones 3 y 4. Por favor sigue la recomendación de @Aprendiz y mejora tu respuesta haciendo clic en [Editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/282932/edit)